# javascript pagination per url

Tags: javascript, json

I'm trying but I can't. I wonder if there is a way to create a paging system through buttons and parameters in the URL to display content (10 texts per page) Please someone help me, give me a light

I have this code, but I don't understand what I'm doing anymore, I have a headache right now and I really don't know how to do it

The code

```
let content = document.querySelector('.content');
let behind = document.querySelector('.behind');
let forward = document.querySelector('.forward');

let text = [
  "texto 1",
  "texto 2",
  "texto 3",
  "texto 4",
  "texto 5",
  "texto 1",
  "texto 2",
  "texto 3",
  "texto 4",
  "texto 5",
  "texto 1",
  "texto 2",
  "texto 3",
  "texto 4",
  "texto 5",
  "texto 1",
  "texto 2",
  "texto 3",
  "texto 4",
  "texto 5",
];


let items = text.length;
let limit = 5;
let pageActual = 1;
let page = Math.ceil(items / limit);

let pText = document.createElement('p');

pText.textContent = text;
content.appendChild(pText);

// JUST FOR SEE
//console.log(`[•] O valor limite é ${limit}<br>[•] O valor total de textos é ${text.length}<br> [•] E o valor de paginas é ${page}`);




const url_string = (window.location.href).toLowerCase();
const url = new URL(url_string);
const p = url.searchParams.get("p");

var host = `https://pagination01.netlify.com/index.html?p=`;
var pages = [host + pageActual];

function prev(current, pages) {
  var index = pages.indexOf(current);
  if (index === 0) {
    return pages[pages.length - 1];
  }
  return pages[index - 1];
}

function next(current, pages) {
  let index = pages.indexOf(current);
  if (index === pages - 1) {
    return pages[0];
  }
  return pages[index + 1];
}

behind.addEventListener('click', function() {
  let newUrl = prev(host, pages);
  window.location.href = newUrl;
});

forward.addEventListener('click', function() {
  let newUrl = next(host, pages);
  window.location.href = newUrl;
});
```

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>P.A.G.I.N.A.T.I.O.N</title>
</head>
<body>

  <div class="content">

  </div>
  page 01
  <a class="behind">prev</a>
  <a class="forward">next</a>

  <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Please help a beginner stupid :(

Comment: Does it have to be with url param? Might make more sense (if you want this in javascript only) to use hash, as url param changes would reload the page, where as hash would not. Also the code you shared doesn't really seem to do what you hope it would be doing

Comment: @Icepickle can you help me? I'm injecting Content dynamically and I don't care exactly on the reload page, I just wanted to do a page without lib but I can't

Comment: Yes, I can help you, but that would just be stopping your own development, and I don't see that you have even tried it based on the code I see. The things you will most likely need, are `Array.slice` to take a part of an array with takes a startIndex, and endIndex of what you like to take (so you can split the array) and some verification to check wether there is still a next page or it should restart. Why not try it without page reload first, from on then you just need to repeat the logic based on the parameter in the url

Comment: @Icepickle I will really try but I don't find any tutorial, could you recommend me something?  please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A very basic version of this using `hashchange` for changing pages would be the following option.

To show a part of an array based on page and pageSize, you could use `Array.slice`

```
function showPage( page, pageSize, target ) {
  output.innerHTML = '<ul>';
  for (let text of texts.slice( page * pageSize, (page + 1) * pageSize )) {
    output.innerHTML += `<li>${text}</li>`;
  }
  output.innerHTML += '</ul>';
}
```

In this case, it will take the part of the array starting at position `page * pageSize` and take it till `(page + 1) * pageSize`

To make the code easier, create a few helper functions that:

- read the currentPage and return it as an integer
- that change to a certain page ensuring that the page would be in range

For example, to read in this case, I use the hash, and read the next parameter after `page` (note that is a very basic way)

```
function getCurrentPage() {
  const hash = window.location.hash;

  if (!hash) {
    return 0;
  }
  const parts = hash.split('/');
  return parseInt( parts[parts.findIndex( p => p === 'page')+1]);
}
```

And I have a `changePage` function that will validate the `targetPage` before navigating

```
function changePage( targetPage ) {
  const maxPages = Math.ceil( texts.length / pageSize );
  if (targetPage < 0) {
    targetPage = maxPages - 1;
  } else if (targetPage >= maxPages) {
    targetPage = 0;
  }
  document.location = document.location.pathname + `#/page/${targetPage}`;
}
```

Then your `previous` and `next` functions become ridiculously easy :)

```
function next() {
  changePage( getCurrentPage() + 1 );
}

function previous() {
  changePage( getCurrentPage() - 1 );
}
```

And if you throw it all together, you get something like this (now it's up to you adapting it for your solution)

```js
const texts = [...new Array(30)].map( (v, i) => `Text item ${i}` );
const pageSize = 10;
const output = document.querySelector('#output');
const btnNext = document.querySelector('#btnNext');
const btnPrevious = document.querySelector('#btnPrevious');
const currentPage = document.querySelector('#currentPage');

function showPage( page, pageSize, target ) {
  output.innerHTML = '<ul>';
  for (let text of texts.slice( page * pageSize, (page + 1) * pageSize )) {
    output.innerHTML += `<li>${text}</li>`;
  }
  output.innerHTML += '</ul>';
}

function getCurrentPage() {
  const hash = window.location.hash;
  
  if (!hash) {
    return 0;
  }
  const parts = hash.split('/');
  return parseInt( parts[parts.findIndex( p => p === 'page')+1]);
}

function showCurrentPage() {
  const curPage = getCurrentPage();
  currentPage.textContent = 'Page: ' + ( curPage + 1 );
  showPage( curPage, pageSize, output );
}

function changePage( targetPage ) {
  const maxPages = Math.ceil( texts.length / pageSize );
  if (targetPage < 0) {
    targetPage = maxPages - 1;
  } else if (targetPage >= maxPages) {
    targetPage = 0;
  }
  document.location = document.location.pathname + `#/page/${targetPage}`;
}

function next() {
  changePage( getCurrentPage() + 1 );
}

function previous() {
  changePage( getCurrentPage() - 1 );
}

btnNext.addEventListener( 'click', next );
btnPrevious.addEventListener( 'click', previous );

showCurrentPage();
window.addEventListener( 'hashchange', showCurrentPage );
```

```html
<div id="output">
</div>
<div class="toolstrip">
  <button type="button" id="btnPrevious">previous</button>
  <span id="currentPage"></span>
  <button type="button" id="btnNext">next</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you ice, I will learn more for make this with url, but this is so really great, thank you

Comment: Man, I stay trying to remove the # from `#/p/${}` but when I make this don't work more, why?

Comment: @Reypic I can't say (as I don't see what you have changed, maybe start a new question) :) the # is used in conjuction with hashchange, so that will change the page without reloading the website. If your version is reloading, it should be enough that you have `showCurrentPage()` called on page load and that you can parse the `getCurrentPage`

Answer (score 0):

This is usually dependent on the API you are calling or the specific implementation of an API you are working on.

When a user visits a page in your application via a browser, the URL in the browser may contain pre-defined `query` arguments. For example:

```
http://www.example.com/search?query=javascript&page=0&size=10
```

Notice that the actual URL for the page is `http://www.example.com/search`. The remaining text represents query arguments: `?query=javascript&page=0&size=10`.

Breaking this text can be broken down further. The `?` indicates to the browser (or a server if this is a request to an API) that the search has variables attached to it. Each variable (more specifically, each query argument) are `key/value` pairs and are separated by `&`s.

Using this specific example, our query has 3 query arguments:

1. query - represents the search term
2. page - represents the specific page we are displaying
3. size - represents the number of items on each page

Since we are the developers of both the front and back ends of our fictional `http://www.example.com`, we decide what valid query arguments are. I will pretend that I am the project lead and I have specified to you that these three arguments are valid and should be implemented by you for this task.

As one of our front-end developers, you can decide how you would like to read these arguments from the URL and then use them as variable to limit the page size and display the appropriate page.

There are many great npm packages available for us to use to achieve this task. Take a look at [`query-string`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/query-string), which is one popular option to assist js developers in reading these values from the browser.

Using `query-string`, we can do the following to get these three variables from the URL:

```
var queryString = require('query-string');

// Get the vars from the URL as an object
var queryArgs = queryString.parse(location.search);

// We must make sure that the page is an integer and not a string
var currentPage = parseInt(queryArgs.page);
// Calculate next and previous pages
var nextPage = currentPage + 1;
// Only subtract 1 if we aren't on page zero
var prevPage = currentPage > 0 ? currentPage - 1 : 0;

// Now use these variable to build your paging links
var BASE_URL = 'http://www.example.com/search&query=' + queryArgs.query + '&size=' + queryArgs.size;

behind.addEventListener('click', function() {
  window.location.href = BASE_URL + '&page=' + prevPage;
});

forward.addEventListener('click', function() {
  window.location.href = BASE_URL + '&page=' + nextPage;
});
```

In truth, you would be better off assigning the page links an href in `document.onReady` and selecting this `a` tags using IDs instead since there should only be one back/prev and forward/next page buttons per page. Do this would not require you to right a click handler as the `a` tag already navigates the to the specified `href` on click.

Comment: requery... I don't stay using node..:(